# C alternative to PHP's explode function

Tags: php, c, explode, strchr

So, i'm looking for a C function that does the equivalent to PHP's explode function.
For those who are not familiar: Explode grabs a string and parses each entry separated by the given char/escape sequence. the best part about this function is its return value, which is an already forged array with all the entries. problem is, this doesn't seem to exist in C. the closest function available is strchr but it returns only a pointer to the first ocurrence of the split.

edit: here's the function, although it has a different behaviour (like the return value differs) it's what i want.

```
int explode(char* str, char* delim, char ***r) {
    char **res = (char**) malloc(sizeof(char*) * strlen(str));
    char *p;
    int i = 0;
    while (p = strtok(str, delim)) {
        res[i] = malloc(strlen(p) + 1);
        strcpy(res[i], p);
        ++i;
        str = NULL;
    }
    res = realloc(res, sizeof(char*) * i);
    *r = res;
    return i;
}
```

it's possible to call it this way:

```
char str[] = "test1|test2|test3";
char** res;
int count = explode(str, "|", &res);
int i;
for (i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
    printf("%s\n", res[i]);
    free(res[i]);
}
free(res);
```

Comment: Did you do some research on this then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `strtok()`. From the man page for it:

> The strtok() function parses a string into a sequence of tokens. On
>   the first call to strtok() the string to be parsed should be specified
>   in str. In each subsequent call that should parse the same string, str
>   should be NULL.
>
> Each call to strtok() returns a pointer to a null-terminated string
>   containing the next token. This string does not include the delimiting
>   byte. If no more tokens are found, strtok() returns NULL.

In other words, loop through your string and keep calling `strtok()` until it returns `NULL` in order to get all the words (that would be split on the delimiters specified to the first call of `strtok()`) returned as `char*`.

Comment: thanks, i had a bit of dificulty setting the function but a friend of mine solved it :) i'll post the solution on the OP